# Elementos de uma Lista são todos iguais

Tags: haskell

Fiz esta definição da função iguais, que verifica se todos os elementos de uma lista são iguais.

```
iguais :: [Float] -> Bool

iguais [x,y] = x == y  

iguais (h:t) = h == (head t)
```

Contudo o resultado não é o desejado. Conseguem dizer qual é o erro ?

Comment: É isso mesmo @CarlosHeuberger

Answer (score 1):

Seu código não funciona porque você não está comparando recursivamente todos os elementos.

Tente esta versão aqui:

```hs
iguais :: [Float] -> Bool
iguais [] = True
iguais [_] = True
iguais (x:xs) = x == (head xs) && iguais xs -- chamada recursiva nesta linha
```

Comment: Em vez de criar o construtor `(x:tail)` é melhor usar `(x:xs)` pois `tail` já é uma função que retorna os elementos restantes da lista e isso pode gerar conflitos. A linha ficaria:
`iguais (x:xs) = x == (head xs) && iguais xs`

Answer (score 1):

Falta recursão no seu código, ou seja, ele tem de repetir essa mesma operação para todos os elementos da lista.
Um exemplo de código simples seria este:

```
iguais :: [Float] -> Bool
iguais [] = False  
iguais (h:t) = elem h t || iguais t
```

Esta é a função elem:

```
elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem x [] = False
elem x (h:t) = if x == h then True else elem x t
```